# Django-Channels/Daphne, incorrect subprotocol response returned

Tags: django, google-chrome, websocket, django-channels

I am using django with django-channels for websocket support, served by daphne.

Apparently, a common hack for authenticating websockets with token authentication is to put the token in the subprotocol argument of the websocket connection. I've done this, with the following AuthMiddleware:

```
@database_sync_to_async
def validate_token(token):
    auth = TokenAuthentication()
    return auth.authenticate_credentials(token.encode("utf-8"))


@database_sync_to_async
def close_connections():
    close_old_connections()


class WebsocketTokenAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        close_connections()
        try:
            token = scope["subprotocols"][0]
            scope["user"] = validate_token(token)
            return self.inner(scope)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

The consumer just checks whether or not there is a user in the scope, and calls `await self.accept()` if there is.

This works fine on Firefox, but on Chrome, errors in the browser with 'Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' but no response was received'. I am aware the chrome is stricter on these things, which presumably is why it works in firefox.